# Auto increment value in javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, increment

I'm trying to auto increment a properties value each time I instantiate a new instance of the class. This is what my class constructor looks (I abstracted it down just a bit):

```
var Playlist = function(player, args){
    var that = this;
    this.id = ?; //Should auto increment
    this.tracks = [];
    this.ready = false;
    this.unloaded = args.length;
    this.callback = undefined;
    this.onready = function(c){
        that.callback = c;
    };
    this.add = function(tracks){
        for(var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++){
            this.tracks.push(tracks[i]);
            this.resolve(i);
        }
    };
    this.resolve = function(i){
        SC.resolve(that.tracks[i]).then(function(data){
            that.tracks[i] = data;
            if(that.unloaded > 0){
                that.unloaded--;
                if(that.unloaded === 0){
                    that.ready = true;
                    that.callback();
                }
            }
        });
    };
    player.playlists.push(this);
    return this.add(args);
};

var playlist1 = new Playlist(player, [url1,url2...]); //Should be ID 0
var playlist2 = new Playlist(player, [url1,url2...]); //Should be ID 1
```

I'd like to not define an initial variable that I increment in the global scope. Could anyone hint me in the right direction? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to create a private variable that you can increment.

```
var Playlist = (function() {
  var nextID = 0;
  return function(player, args) {
    this.id = nextID++;
    ...
  };
})();
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Still don't fully understand how but I'm sure I'll get my head around it. Thanks!

Comment: @cursedphil Be careful. You'll get addicted haha. I think [this article](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/an-introduction-to-iffes-immediately-invoked-function-expressions.html) does a pretty good job of explaining what they do.

Comment: @cursedphil In the following [Article](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/) you can see how the code works provided by Mike C, is really interesting as these private environments are created, Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Playlist.id = 0` somewhere in your code, then increment it in the constructor and assign the new value to the instance property, as: `this.id = Playlist.id++`.
This suffers from the fact that it is not well encapsulated, so it could be misused.

Otherwise, I was to propose the solution described by Mike C, but he already set a good answer that contains such an idea, so...

Comment: How would this work? Does `Playlist` (the constructor) retain data between initializations? I thought ES6 Generator functions were like that, can you really do that outside of ES6?

Comment: `Playlist` is a function, that is an object, you can set whatever property on it and freely access it from within the constructor. Why not? The object `Playlist` does not change between different invocations of the function `Playlist`.

Comment: @sg.cc By assigning it to `Playlist` it'd be the same as if you have done `var stuff = {}; stuff.id = 0;`. As skypjack said, it's just an object.

Comment: Ohhh. I thought it was a constructor function rather than an object. Thank you!

Comment: @sg.cc It's both. Every function is an object but not every object is a function.